# Saving Blob Object As a File On Server

Tags: php, jquery, magento, blob

Using jQuery plugin called cropper, I am able to retrieve the cropped image as blob object. Now I need to save this blob object as a file on my server. The code for that is:

```
$('#image').cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob) {
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('croppedImage', blob);
    formData.append('form_key', window.FORM_KEY);

    $.ajax('/upload.php', {
        method: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my upload.php:

```
<?php
$blob = $_POST['croppedImage'];
//return $blob;
file_put_contents('/media/crop_products/test.png', $blob);
?>
```

It is not saving it on the server. What I am dong here? This request is made from an admin page in magento.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for that path? Anything in the error logs?

Comment: Also, `contentType:false` is used for multipart/form-data forms to send files. Look in `$_FILES`

Comment: yeah nothing in the error file. Permissions are also correct

Comment: the file is getting saved but its empty, am i reading the blob object correctly?

Comment: I'm betting the file gets *created* not *saved*. Run `$a = get_defined_vars();unset($a['GLOBALS'], $a['_ENV'], $a['_SERVER']);print_r($a);` before `$blob = ...`  And see exactly what you're sending.

Comment: getting this:  [_FILES] => Array
        (
            [file] => Array
                (
                    [name] => blob
                    [type] => image/png
                    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpC9g8rU
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 1062301
                )

        )

    [blob] =>

Comment: I guess you were right, blob is empty, how do i fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106572/discussion-between-alex-tartan-and-mayank).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're sending the data with `contentType:false`, it will be accessible in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`.

The comment exchange confirms this.

Your `$_FILES` array is (according to comments):

```
[_FILES] => Array ( 
    [file] => Array ( 
        [name] => blob 
        [type] => image/png 
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpC9g8rU 
        [error] => 0 
        [size] => 1062301 
    ) 
)
```

To upload it:

```
move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/media/crop_products/test.png"
);
```

Note: `move_uploaded_file` needs a full path as a second argument (the target location) and also, the folder should be writable.

Comment: Thank you very much! `$_FILES` array was the clue!